# Returning only the unique values from two strings in Spotfire

Tags: string, date, comparison, missing-data, spotfire

I am trying to compare two columns a + b. Column A is populated with a string of data and Column B with another string of data. I am using the below formula in a custom column to return unique values yet it does not appear to work for instances. Formula being used to identify the unique values:

```
right(RXReplace([expected dates],[dates],"","g"),Len(RXReplace([expected dates],[dates],"","g")))
```

[[image: sample of the data being compared]

this formula sometimes returns all the dates in the expected dates column when those dates exist in the dates column.

I have tried this formula

```
 right(RXReplace([expected dates],[dates],"","g"),Len(RXReplace([expected dates],[dates],"","g"))).
```

I was expecting the dates which were missing in the dates column to be returned
[[image: sample of what was expected to be returned]

Comment: Image of your data is as useful as this: [image of sql](https://ibb.co/PD9m21X)  PLEASE don't use images of data. If I wrote a really nice but long solution query, took a screenshot of it, and added that image as an answer, would you be annoyed about the unnecessary transcription effort? Please don't use images of data, just copy/paste some data into the question and format it using the `{}` button in the toolbar. ps: You can use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to create ascii tables.

Comment: It isn't clear (even when I consider the images) what you "expect". Is it that you want the maximum number of matches between the date literals when comparing A to B? It looks like B is constant, is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you can get this result with a simple expression, as you are effectively comparing two arrays. I am suggesting to create a calculated column using a TERR expression function, if that is available to you.

I was also not sure of what you expected in return. Do you want only the elements in [expected dates] that are not in [dates], or do you want all the differences, i.e. including the dates in [dates] that are not in [expected dates] (extra dates)?

The code I am suggesting is:

```
checkDifference = function(A,B) {
    Av=strsplit(A,',')[[1]]
    Bv=strsplit(B,',')[[1]]
    Cv=c(setdiff(Bv,Av),setdiff(Av,Bv))
    C=paste(Cv,collapse=',')
    return (C)
}

output=mapply(FUN=checkDifference,input1,input2)
```

The function first splits both columns into vectors, applies a set difference, joins the resulting vector back to a string and returns it. A TERR expression function assumes inputs and outputs are entire columns of data, that is why I used the mapply function to apply the formula row by row.

In this case I am looking for all differences, if you only want the elements in [expected dates] that are not in [dates] you would replace this line, which concatenates both differences:

```
Cv=c(setdiff(Bv,Av),setdiff(Av,Bv)
```

with this, i.e. only the set of items that are in Bv but not Av:

```
Cv=setdiff(Bv,Av)
```

In order to put this code into Spotfire, you would from the top menu choose Data > Data function properties > Expression functions tab > New..

Then in the editor copy and paste the code, give it a name e.g. TERR_checkDates, Function type=Column function, Return type=String, Category=Text functions.

This function will now be available in the list of Functions that can be used when you create a new calculated column. You should find it in the list of available functions.

Create the new column with this expression:

```
TERR_checkDates([dates],[expected dates])
```